# XtraGrid Disable repository item button on specific cell's mouse move

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

I want to disable **ButtonEdit** editor cell whenever mouse is entered in other specific cell. How can I achieve this functionality?

[image: Disable]

Like, whenever my mouse hovers over **Ammar** cell then **Remove** button must be disabled like in 1st and 3rd row.

**NOTE:** *Select* column is `RepositoryItemButtonEdit` column.

This is my `MouseMove` event:

```
Private Sub gridViewLevel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Get a View at the current point.
    Dim view As BaseView = GridControl.GetViewAt(e.Location)
    ' Retrieve information on the current View element.
    Dim baseHI As BaseHitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location)
    Dim gridHI As GridHitInfo = TryCast(baseHI, GridHitInfo)
    'Get Field Value
    Dim fieldName As String = gridHI.View.GetRowCellValue(gridHI.RowHandle, gridHI.Column)

    Dim row As DataRow = Nothing

    If Not gridHI Is Nothing Then
        lblHitInfo.Text = fieldName
        row = gridHI.View.GetDataRow(gridHI.RowHandle)
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

In this way, I got the `DataRow` but what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397239/xtragrid-get-respositoryitembuttonedit-row-index) question! I am able to get this issue solved.

I have modified this event as follows!

```
Private Sub GrdView_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Get a View at the current point.
    Dim view As BaseView = GrdCntrlMain.GetViewAt(e.Location)
    ' Retrieve information on the current View element.
    Dim baseHI As BaseHitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location)
    Dim gridHI As GridHitInfo = TryCast(baseHI, GridHitInfo)

    If gridHI.InColumn Or gridHI.InDataRow Then
        Dim cellValue As String = gridHI.View.GetRowCellValue(gridHI.RowHandle, gridHI.Column)
        If cellValue = "Ammar" Then
            GrdView.FocusedRowHandle = gridHI.RowHandle
            GrdView.FocusedColumn = GrdView.Columns("Select")

            GrdView.ShowEditor()

            Dim editor = GrdView.ActiveEditor

            editor.Enabled = False

        Else

            GrdView.FocusedRowHandle = gridHI.RowHandle
            GrdView.FocusedColumn = GrdView.Columns("Select")

            GrdView.ShowEditor()

            Dim editor = GrdView.ActiveEditor

            editor.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Though it will be called on every cell but you can restrict it to only for one column.

Answer (score 0):

It is not absolute clear to me what you try to achive, but I would try to use the `CustomRowCellEdit` Event to influence the editor depending on the rows data. In this event you can set `e.RepositoryItem` corresponding to your logic, e.g. set it to a readonly instance of a buttonedit or an not-readonly one.

In general you can cast the row object to your actual datatype like this:

```
var myData = gridView.GetRow(rowHandle) as MyData;

if(myData.Foo)
   e.RepositoryItem = myReadonlyEditor;
else
   e.RepositoryItem = myNormalEditor;
```

Comment: `e.RepositoryItem` is not available in `MouseMove` event.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher: Yes, you are right. I suggested the `CustomRowCellEdit` Event, so the codesnipped referres to that event and not `MouseMove`. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: That event won't help because `CustomRowCellEdit` event fires on every cell. Whenever you make a change or update any cell value, it will get called. Moreover, I have requirement to make it on `MouseMove` event.

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher: As stated in my answer "It is not absolute clear to me what you try to achive" I can not, sorry. I did not want to solve the problem for you, I just tried to show a possibility to make buttons readonly depending on the data of the row, as that was part of the problem and I thought it could bring you a step further.

Comment: Bro, the requirement is, whenever Mouse is over **Ammar** cell as highlighted by left red block then the button against that row (as highlighted by red block at right side) gets disable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GridView.CustomDrawCell`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) event to draw the disabled state in cell. For this you need to call [`GridView.InvalidateRowCell`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_InvalidateRowCelltopic) method to redraw a particular cell every time when the cell meet your conditions.
Here is example:

```
Private disabledRowHandle? As Int32
Private disabledColumn As GridColumn

Private Sub GrdView_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GrdView.MouseMove
    ' Get a View at the current point.
    Dim view = TryCast(GrdCntrlMain.GetViewAt(e.Location), GridView)
    ' Retrieve information on the current View element.
    Dim gridHI = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location)

    Dim redrawPrevious = True
    Dim drawDisabled = False

    If gridHI.InColumn Or gridHI.InDataRow Then
        Dim cellValue As String = gridHI.View.GetRowCellValue(gridHI.RowHandle, gridHI.Column)

        If cellValue = "Ammar" Then
            If Not disabledRowHandle.Equals(gridHI.RowHandle) Then
                drawDisabled = True
            Else
                redrawPrevious = False
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If redrawPrevious AndAlso disabledRowHandle.HasValue Then
        Dim rowHandle = disabledRowHandle.Value
        disabledRowHandle = Nothing

        view.InvalidateRowCell(rowHandle, disabledColumn)
    End If

    If drawDisabled Then
        If IsNothing(disabledColumn) Then
            disabledColumn = GrdView.Columns("Select")
        End If

        disabledRowHandle = gridHI.RowHandle
        view.InvalidateRowCell(disabledRowHandle.Value, disabledColumn)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GrdView_CustomDrawCell(sender As Object, e As RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs) Handles GrdView.CustomDrawCell
    If disabledRowHandle.Equals(e.RowHandle) AndAlso e.Column Is disabledColumn Then
        Dim currentColor = e.Appearance.ForeColor
        Dim currentUseForeColor = e.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor

        e.Appearance.ForeColor = CommonSkins.GetSkin(UserLookAndFeel.Default).Colors.GetColor(CommonColors.DisabledText)
        e.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = True

        e.DefaultDraw()

        e.Appearance.ForeColor = currentColor
        e.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = currentUseForeColor

        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```